# Incorrect values when plotting from file containing time data - gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to generate a graph with gnuplot but it seems that it doesn't show the correct values:
Data are:

```
03/18/2014 15:00:50                32,4
03/18/2014 14:00:48                32,4
03/18/2014 13:00:48               32,42
03/18/2014 12:00:44                32,4
03/18/2014 11:00:42                122,2
03/18/2014 10:00:47                22,4
03/18/2014 09:00:37                53,9
03/18/2014 08:00:35                14,2
```

The sh is:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set title "Plot x^2"
set terminal png
set output "output.png"

set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
#set datafile sep ','
set xdata time
set timefmt '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
plot 'pepe.csv' using 1:2 with lines
```

It shows me:
[image]

Comment: What do you want it to look like? Be specific.

Comment: Thanks. I would like that the line have the second value (32,4-32,4-32,42-32,4-28,7-23-6)....The X asys is fine but the second value don't shows the correct values

Comment: I'm not where those numbers are coming from, is it one column minus the other? Can you edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: I edit the data. The graph is simply a time graph of a tablespace size. Thanks

Comment: It looks like gnuplot is having trouble parsing both columns of data.  Applying the setting `set decimalsign ','` may help.

Comment: @andyras dont work :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@andyras' suggestion of `set decimalsign ','` is helpful but if you have a space in the time format then it counts as **more than one column**. Quoting the documentation:

> Each set of non-blank characters in the timedata counts as one column in the using n:n specification. Thus 11:11 25/12/76 21.0 consists of three columns. To avoid confusion, gnuplot requires that you provide a complete using specification if your file contains timedata.

This means that you need to change `using 1:2` to `using 1:3`.

Using your original data, this script works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set title "Plot x^2"
set terminal png
set output "output.png"

set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set decimalsign ','
set timefmt '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
set xdata time

plot 'decimal.txt' u 1:3 with lines
```

Output:
[image: image showing correct plot]

Alternatively, you could use a different data separator in your datafile, such as a `,` and the time will only count as one column. To do this you add the line `set datafile sep ','` to your script.

**edit**: you might want to also consider using the `pngcairo` terminal (`set term pngcairo`), as it looks a lot better:

[image: plot using pngcairo]

Comment: Good guess :) With the `pngcairo` terminal the graph looks much better http://i.stack.imgur.com/XkkPK.png

Comment: @Christoph I've included your masterpiece